# Upload files via SFTP with phpseclib

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I am uploading CSV files via SFTP with using phpseclib class.
I do the following:

```
include('vendor/autoload.php');
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;
$sftp = new SFTP($sftpServerHost);
$Key = new RSA();
$Key->setPassword($sftpKeyPassword);
$Key->loadKey(file_get_contents($sftpKey));
if (!$sftp->login($sftpUserName, $Key)) {
   throw new Exception('Login failed');
}else{
   $sftp->chdir('upload');
   $sftp->put($filename, $output);
}
```

$output - is a content of a CSV file.
If the content is less than ~40 lines then file is uploading with no issues though if the content is >40 lines then the script hangs for a while then outputs several lines of error:

```
PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 3167
PHP Notice:  Connection closed prematurely in /vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 3025
PHP Notice:  Connection closed by server in /vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 3373
PHP Notice:  Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS in /vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2027
PHP Notice:  Connection closed prematurely in /vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 3599
```

As a result file is not uploaded.
Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the SSH logs? You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', SSH2::LOG_COMPLEX);` at the top and then `$sftp->getLog()` after the unsuccessful file upload. Since the logs are liable to be fairly large I'd post them on pastebin.com and edit your post to include the link.

Comment: Thank you @neubert, I did what you suggested and here is the log: https://pastebin.com/V5bXtSLa please let me know if it helps

Comment: My initial thought: try lowering phpseclib's `$sftp_packet_size`. Right now it's 4096. Maybe try lowering it to 1024 or some such: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.6/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L1956 Alternatively, maybe try lowering the window size significantly. Right now it's 0x7FFFFFFF. Maybe try lowering it to like 1024 as well if `$sftp_packet_size` doesn't help: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.6/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L567

Comment: dear @neubert, lowering phpseclib's $sftp_packet_size helped, thank you very much for your help!